# CSS Colors flickering when animation ends

Tags: css, safari

```
.item {
    width: 15px;
    height: 19px;
    padding: 4px 4px 0px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d62957;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .6s linear;
    -o-transition: all .6s linear;
    transition: all .6s linear;
}

.item:hover {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .6s linear;
    -o-transition: all .6s linear;
    transition: all .6s linear;
}
```

The transition causes the menu options to grow in size when they are hovered over and to change color; when the div is no longer hovered over and the transition ends, some of the menu options (usually not the one that was hovered over, but all the rest) turn an odd bright purple color that is not defined anywhere in the CSS.

I can only reproduce this in Safari (my primary browser); I tested it in Chrome and Firefox and the issue did not happen.

http://codepen.io/take_ninetynine/pen/RroXjP

Here is a screenshot of the error as I see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA9QQ.png

Comment: Would you like reproduce it on codepen.io and share de link? to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Codepen link added. It might be worth mentioning that while I was recreating the styling in codepen, the underline color on the links was the same undefined color that the buttons are turning into.

Comment: I am testing your code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZRvYB it works fine for me, in chrome and safary, maybe is you share an screenshoot with the bug.

Comment: Screenshot added. http://i.stack.imgur.com/TA9QQ.png